# BEM CSS with common styles

Tags: css, frontend, bem

I have a bit of confusion when it comes to using global styles.  Consider the following:

Say I have a stylesheet that defines how buttons should be made:

```
/* Button.CSS */
button {
  background-color: #CCC;
}

button.Blue {
  background-color: #00F;
  color: #FFF;
}

Button.Blue.Hollow {
  background-color: none;
  border: 1px solid #00F;
  color: #00F;
}
```

and then you use the button in the template with your standard BEM notation (I'll use the Block__Element--Modifier notation)

```
<!-- index.html -->
<ul class="Widget">
  <li class="Widget__Item">
    <button class="Widget__Button"></button>
  </li>
  <li class="Widget__Item">
    <button class="Widget__Button Blue"></button>
  </li>
  <li class="Widget__Item">
    <button class="Widget__Button Blue Hollow"></button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Is that the acceptable practice to mix classes like that?  I feel like i'm violating some rule of encapsulated block styling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I feel like i'm violating some rule of encapsulated block styling.

Indeed.
`Button` should be a block, not an element. `Blue` and `Hollow` are modifiers.

With the `Block__Element--Modifier` syntax, your code should be:

```
.Button {
  background-color: #CCC;
}
.Button--Blue {
  background-color: #00F;
  color: #FFF;
}
.Button--BlueHollow {
  background-color: none;
  border: 1px solid #00F;
  color: #00F;
}

<ul class="Widget">
  <li class="Widget__Item">
    <button class="Button"></button>
  </li>
  <li class="Widget__Item">
    <button class="Button Button--Blue"></button>
  </li>
  <li class="Widget__Item">
    <button class="Button Button--Blue Button--BlueHollow"></button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Alternatively, you can use a `MyBlock-myElement.myModifier` syntax (closer to your way):

```
.Button {
  background-color: #CCC;
}
.Button.blue {
  background-color: #00F;
  color: #FFF;
}
.Button.blue.hollow {
  background-color: none;
  border: 1px solid #00F;
  color: #00F;
}

<ul class="Widget">
  <li class="Widget-item">
    <button class="Button"></button>
  </li>
  <li class="Widget-item">
    <button class="Button blue"></button>
  </li>
  <li class="Widget-item">
    <button class="Button blue hollow"></button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ah, that sounds good.  I can still modify the last item if i wish, correct?  Say.. `<button class="Button Button--Blue Button--BlueHollow">` was last, i could append `<button class="Button Button--Blue Button--BlueHollow Widget__Button-Last">` along with `.Widget__Button-Last { color: red; }`?

Comment: It's better to use a modifier on the block `Button`. The block `Button` doesn't need to know if it is on the last position. It just need to display with the "red" variant.

Comment: Thanks Tarh!  To supplement your answer, this helped: http://bem.info/tutorials/start-with-project-stub/#Mix-of-blocks-and-elements